# adding rows with values of '0' for missing years

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, tidy

I have a question that is somewhat similar to others that have been posted, but after looking thoroughly at several posts, I can't get the code to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

My data frame looks like, this:

```
'data.frame':   501 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Tattoo.MUM   : Factor w/ 250 levels "1004","1007",..: 76 76 76 81 81 81 85 85 85 85 ...
 $ OffspringMUMs: int  4 4 4 4 4 4 11 11 11 11 ...
 $ YearBIRTH.CUB: int  1988 1990 1991 1988 1991 2007 1989 1991 1992 1993 ...
 $ YearBIRTH.MUM: int  1991 1991 NA NA NA NA 1987 1987 1987 1987 ...
 $ OFFSpYR      : int  2 1 1 1 2 1 1 4 3 3 ...
```

A few lines here:

```
structure(list(Tattoo.MUM = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("10454", "1045A", "1045X", "12392", 
"1601", "22", "27", "29", "41", "424X", "60"), class = "factor"), 
OffspringMUMs = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), YearBIRTH.CUB = c(1989L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1990L, 1991L, 
1993L, 1989L, 1988L, 1988L, 1989L, 1991L, 1994L, 2015L, 2012L, 
2015L, 2005L, 2009L, 2010L, 1996L, 1998L, 2000L, 2001L, 2006L
), YearBIRTH.MUM = c(1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2005L, 
2005L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L), OFFSpYR = c(1L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Tattoo.MUM", 
"OffspringMUMs", "YearBIRTH.CUB", "YearBIRTH.MUM", "OFFSpYR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

I want to add new rows for all missing years (YearBIRTH.CUB) in Tattoo.MUM keeping the rest of the values the same and adding '0' to OFFSpYR.

Like so:

```
structure(list(Tattoo.MUM = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L), .Label = c("10454", "1045A", "1045X", "12392", "1601", 
"22", "27", "29", "41", "424X", "60"), class = "factor"), OffspringMUMs = c(11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L), YearBIRTH.CUB = c(1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1989L, 1988L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 
1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 2015L, 2012L, 2015L, 2005L, 2009L, 
2010L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
2004L, 2005L, 2006L), YearBIRTH.MUM = c(1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 
1987L, 1987L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 
1987L, 1987L, 1987L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2005L, 2005L, 1994L, 1994L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L
), OFFSpYR = c(1L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Tattoo.MUM", "OffspringMUMs", 
"YearBIRTH.CUB", "YearBIRTH.MUM", "OFFSpYR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-35L))
```

I've tried:

```
 library(tidyr)
 library(dplyr)

 df1 <- pedMUM %>% group_by(Tattoo.MUM, OffspringMUMs) %>% complete(YearBIRTH.CUB = full_seq(YearBIRTH.CUB,1)) %>% fill(OFFSpYR=0)

library(data.table)

df1 <- setDT(pedMUM)[CJ(Tattoo.MUM=Tattoo.MUM, OffspringMUMs=OffspringMUMs, YearBIRTH.MUM=YearBIRTH.MUM, YearBIRTH.CUB=seq(min(YearBIRTH.CUB), max(YearBIRTH.CUB)), unique=TRUE),
                 on=.(Tattoo.MUM, OffspringMUMs, YearBIRTH.CUB),  roll=T]
```

I am obviously using tidyr, dplyr, and data.table wrongly because none have given me the results I want.

I've had a look at the following posts:

[Add rows with missing years by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799109/add-rows-with-missing-years-by-group)

[Adding rows with values of "0" to a dataframe with missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538660/adding-rows-with-values-of-0-to-a-dataframe-with-missing-data?noredirect=1)

[Find missing month after grouping with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520558/find-missing-month-after-grouping-with-dplyr)

And even tried loops:

[R code - clever loop to add rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338886/r-code-clever-loop-to-add-rows)

but I get confused when I try to determine the year sequence for each Tattoo.MUM within the loop.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add the result from dput(head(df1)), instead of typing out a few lines, and check the lines you did write, not sure if they are clear enough. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you! I've edited it as you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `complete()` before, but the following seems to work. `nesting()` allows you to keep two variables together, `=full_seq()` allows you to expand the values of a variable, `fill=list()` allows you to fill in blanks.

```
pedMUM <- structure(list(Tattoo.MUM = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L,
7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 10L,
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("10454", "1045A", "1045X", "12392",
"1601", "22", "27", "29", "41", "424X", "60"), class = "factor"),
OffspringMUMs = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L,
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), YearBIRTH.CUB = c(1989L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1990L, 1991L,
1993L, 1989L, 1988L, 1988L, 1989L, 1991L, 1994L, 2015L, 2012L,
2015L, 2005L, 2009L, 2010L, 1996L, 1998L, 2000L, 2001L, 2006L
), YearBIRTH.MUM = c(1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2005L,
2005L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L), OFFSpYR = c(1L,
4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Tattoo.MUM",
"OffspringMUMs", "YearBIRTH.CUB", "YearBIRTH.MUM", "OFFSpYR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-24L))

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- pedMUM %>%
    group_by(Tattoo.MUM) %>% # find min and max year for each mum
    mutate(
        minyear=min(YearBIRTH.CUB, na.rm=TRUE),
        maxyear=max(YearBIRTH.CUB, na.rm=TRUE)
    ) %>% 
    complete( # complete table
        nesting(Tattoo.MUM, minyear, maxyear, OffspringMUMs, YearBIRTH.MUM),
        YearBIRTH.CUB=full_seq(YearBIRTH.CUB, 1),
        fill=list(OFFSpYR=0)
        ) %>% 
    filter(YearBIRTH.CUB>=minyear & YearBIRTH.CUB<=maxyear) %>% # remove unwanted years
    select(names(pedMUM))  # return original column order
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but none of those are working...

The first option provides an extra row for each year in the dataset so not really what I wanted, and the second one gives the following error: Error in if (any((x - rng[1])%%period > tol)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Still doesn't work if I use the complete dataset (no NAs) and just the 3 variables I'm interested in:
df1 <- pedMUM %>%   
  complete(YrBIRTH.CUBS,nesting(Tattoo.MUM, YrBIRTH.MUMS), 
           YrBIRTH.CUBS=full_seq(YrBIRTH.CUBS, 1), 
           fill=list(OFFSpYR=0))

Comment: I've now included the complete script which works for me. You have `YrBIRTH.CUBS` appearing twice in your code, which is probably not allowed. Also check the spelling and case of your variable names.

Comment: Ah so you don't actually want the full sequence of years for each mother.

Comment: Thanks! (apologies about the variables names, I was sloppy and was using a different data frame today). 
For some reason the filter line of code gave me an error: Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  names(pedMUM)

Comment: but I filtered out the unwanted years in a separate line and that it worked!

Comment: Is your version of R and all your packages packages up to date?